# Magento 2 : get all store list by sort order

Tags: magento2, multistore, stores

I want to get store list sort by sort order. How to get it?

I just use this code. Which code i need to add ?

```
$stores = $this->storeManager->getStores();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$stores = $this->storeManager->getStores();
uasort(
    $stores,
    function (\Magento\Store\Model\Store $storeA, \Magento\Store\Model\Store $storeB) {
        return $storeA->getSortOrder() <=> $storeB->getSortOrder();
    }    
);
```

Now the variable `$stores` should contain all your stores sorted by `sort_order`.

Comment: Is it possible in Magento way?

Comment: what do you mean by "magento way"?

Comment: I'm just asking about is there any other way instead of uasort();

Comment: Because, $stores; inside uasort() returns error in sublime text editor for something like syntax error so.

Comment: Oups. Sorry. I got the order of the parameters wrong. I've updated the answer

Comment: you can use collections, but that's less of a magento 2 way than it is to sort them using `uasort`.